# Variable Coloring of Slopegraph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing R code that generates reports for 15 different groups. I am making some data visualizations that will be provided along with the reports. I really think a slopegraph would help communicate change from midblock (midterm) to final.

The dataframe is structured as:

```
Domain   Means   Test
A          3    Midblock
B          3    Midblock
C          3    Midblock
D          3    Midblock
E          3    Midblock
F          3    Midblock
G          3    Midblock
A          4      Final
B          4      Final
C          4      Final
D          4      Final
E          4      Final
F          4      Final
G          4      Final
```

The code I'm using is:

```
Domains_Graph$Test <- 
    fct_relevel(factor(Domains_Graph$Test), 
                "Mid-block", "Final")
```

```
plot <- ggplot(data = Domains_Graph, aes(x = Test, y = Means, group = Domain, color = Domain)) +
geom_line(size = 2) +
geom_point(size = 3) +
scale_color_brewer(palette = "Purples") +  # Use Purples color palette
ggtitle(str_wrap("Title", width = 40)) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = c(1, 0))) +
theme_minimal()
print(plot)
`
```

[image]

If you view the image, you'll notice that domain A has a huge change from time point 1 to timepoint 2. I want to make this the darkest line of the group.

Does anyone know how I can rework a dataframe/my current code to allow the use of a growth value to variablly change to dictate color.

I've attempted to use scale_color_gradient2 (using sc() low, mid, high, but the classification of "color = " in the ggplot() portion will not accept a value I've calculated in another dataframe (e.g., I calculated the growth values between the two time points for another figure in another dataframe (X$growth).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like we want two things:

1. Order the colors based on the change in Means per Domain, with the steepest (A) shown darkest.
2. Show the legend in order of Domain.

We can make `Domain` into a factor ordered by the change in value, and separately specify the order of the levels in the legend (using the `breaks` argument of the color scale, to get colors that are ordered by change, but which appear in alphabetical order in the legend.

EDIT: using adaptation of real data provided by @Allan-Cameron

[image]

```
Domains_Graph <- data.frame(
   Domain = rep(LETTERS[1:7], 2), 
   Means = c(2.65, 2.76, 2.74, 3.05, 2.8, 2.8, 2.9, 3.25, 
             3.12, 3.12, 3.25, 2.98, 3.1, 3.17),           
   Test = factor(rep(c('Mid-block', 'Final'), each = 7), 
                 c('Mid-block', 'Final')))


library(dplyr); library(forcats)
Domains_Graph |>
  # Not needed for updated data, already ordered factor
  # mutate(Test = fct_relevel(factor(Test), "Mid-block", "Final")) |>
  mutate(change = max(Means[Test == "Final"]) - max(Means[Test == "Mid-block"]),
         .by = Domain) |>
  mutate(Domain = factor(Domain) |> fct_reorder(-change)) |>

ggplot(aes(x = Test, y = Means,  group = Domain, color = Domain)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Purples",
                     breaks = LETTERS[1:7]) +  # Use Purples color palette
  ggtitle(str_wrap("Title", width = 40)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = c(1, 0))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

Using data as provided by Allan Cameron

```r
Domains_Graph <- data.frame(Domain = rep(LETTERS[1:7], 2),
                            Means = c(2.65, 2.76, 2.74, 3.05, 2.8, 2.8, 2.9, 3.25, 3.12, 3.12, 3.25, 2.98, 3.1, 3.17),
                            Test = factor(rep(c('Midblock', 'Final'), each = 7),                          
                                          c('Midblock', 'Final')))
```

1. You can `pivot_wider()` your data in order to calculate the difference
   between “Midblock” and “Final” values and create a ranking by difference.
2. We turn it back into a long data.frame with `pivot_longer()` and feed it into
   `ggplot()`.

```r
plot_g <- 
  Domains_Graph |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test,
              values_from = Means) |> 
  mutate(diff = Final - Midblock,
         diff_rank = rank(diff),
         Domain = factor(Domain),
         Domain = fct_reorder(Domain, -diff_rank)) |> 
  pivot_longer(c(Midblock, Final), 
               names_to = "Test",
               values_to = "Means") |> 
  mutate(Test = factor(Test, levels = c("Midblock", "Final"))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Test, y = Means, group = Domain, color = Domain)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 3)

plot_g +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Purples") +
  ggtitle(str_wrap("Title", width = 40)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# with ordering of the legend by letter order (as in Jon Spring's answer)
plot_g +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Purples", breaks = LETTERS[1:7]) +
  ggtitle(str_wrap("Title", width = 40)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]